# Authentication has failed: invalid_clientUnauthorized

Tags: android, google-workspace

I am trying to implement google drive in my app and i have read the documentation and  done whatever has guided and everything went fine but at last i got error that Authentication has failed: invalid_clientUnauthorized

[This is the screen shot of my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHXTc.png)

I have no idea what should i do any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have this error probably because you dont have oauth2.json file.
If your file name is main.py your oauth file should name like this: "main.py-oauth2.json". In oauth2 file you should have acces token to your google account.